# Python Regex Search for three terms

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to Python AND Regex and am a little confused. I want to search through a webpage title for three different terms and if the title matches one I want that printed out (I'm using scrapy so it's printing it for each item). I'm unsure how we get it to search through the three terms? Eg if title has "Dresses|Wallets|Pumps" print it out.

For now I just got it to print the first term in the title

```
c_raw = response.xpath('//title').extract()
c_re = re.search('<title>(.*?) |.*?', c_raw[0])
c = c_re.group(1).lower()
```

I tried

```
c_raw = response.xpath('//title').extract()
c_re = re.search('Dresses|Wallets|Pumps', c_raw[0])
c = c_re.group(0)
```

but some of the c's printed None. I'm also unsure of what `c_raw[0]` is doing? What does the 0 do?
Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: While the below answer helped - adding brackets around Dresses|Wallets|Pumps also worked

Comment: Does it help if you add parentheses around your regex? Like `(Dresses|Wallets|Pumps)`

Comment: You should try to use an XML parser like BeautifulSoup instead of regex when it comes to parsing web pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regular expression that will find which (if any) of your title keywords appear in `c_raw`:

```
regex = re.compile("(?:Dresses)|(?:Wallets)|(?:Pumps)")
print regex.findall(c_raw)
```

The format of `(?:Dresses)` etc., just means match the letters inside the parenthesis in the order they appear together but don't save them as a regex group.

As to what `c_raw[0]` is doing, basically `c_raw` is a string. In python, you can treat strings as if they are arrays of characters. So, `c_raw[0]` is saying, give me the 0th index of the array `c_raw` -- i.e. get the first character of `c_raw`

Answer (score 1):

try this demo from scrapy shell,

```
In [1]: text = "<title>Testing test Pumps abc asdf a</title>"

In [2]: sel = Selector(text=text)

In [3]: sel.xpath('//title').re('Dresses|Wallets|Pumps')
Out[3]: [u'Pumps']
```

I have made an input html to selector object since you haven't provide any specific start-url